# elasticsearch in memory speed

Tags: performance, search, elasticsearch, in-memory

I'm trying to test how much faster would be the in-memory solution with elasticsearch.

For this, I wrote a test in which Im generating ~10milion records and after that performing a text search. Result comes in 3-20ms but there is no difference (at all) when I do the search in memory and without this setting. Is it possible? Is 10million records too small to see any difference? Im not even 100% sure if I enabled the in-memory mode correctly. Im loading the settings from a json file, in which I places some settings I found on internet that was supposed to improve overall solution, but it seems like its not working at all.

The settings regarding index looks like this:

```
"index": {
    "store": {
        "type":"memory"
    },
    "merge": {
        "policy": {
            "use_compound_file": false
        }
    },
    "translog": {
        "flush_threshold": 50000
    },
    "engine": {
        "robin": {
            "refresh_interval": 2
        }
    },
    "cache": {
        "field": {
            "max_size": 500000,
            "expire": "30m"
        }
    }
},
"indices": {
    "memory": {
        "index_buffer_size": 256
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using in-memory storage wisely or not. you can just match what type of storage do you need [here.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-store.html#simplefs)

But, You have to provide storage setting, while creating the index (make sure that index doesn't exists previously)

Try this,

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/" -d'
{
    "settings": {
        "index.store.type": "memory"
    }
}'
```

This will create index, which will stores the index in main memory, using Lucene’s RamIndexStore.

Comment: The in-memory storage option was removed in Elasticsearch 2.0+: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_setting_changes.html#_in_memory_indices